# Speed up for loop iterating over two large (10000s) lists

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to check one list of IP addresses against another list of Networks that it could belong to. The lengths:

```
len(IP_addresses_list) = 31995
len(Network_list) = 54099

    big_dict = {}
    for ip in IP_addresses_list:
        address_and_networks = self.is_subnet_of(ip, Network_list)
        big_dict.update(address_and_networks)

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(big_dict, orient="index")
```

And the loop is verifying whether it belongs to the network by:

```
def is_subnet_of(self, ip, Network_list):
    address_and_networks = {}
    address = ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
    for net in Network_list:
        network = ipaddress.ip_network(net)
        res = network.supernet_of(ipaddress.ip_network(f"{address}/{address.max_prefixlen}"))
        if res:
            if ip in address_and_networks:
                address_and_networks[ip].append(net)
            else:
                address_and_networks[ip] = [net]

    return address_and_networks
```

The `address_and_networks` dict may look like:

```
{
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx": ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/23"],
  "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy": ["yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/24", "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/23"]
}
```

This method is currently painstakingly slow, so slow it's just not feasible to use. I'd like to accelerate this somehow, perhaps by dumping the original lists (`IP_addresses_list, Network_list`) into a dataframe then perform some sweeping execution on the dataframe, by applying the `is_subnet_of` method (maybe something like `dataframe.select` or `dataframe.apply`). Any idea how I can speed this up?

**EDIT**

I streamlined the code further, but I'm still resorting to looping over the dataframes:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"IP_Address": ip_s.map(ipaddress.ip_address),
                            "Network": net_s.map(ipaddress.ip_network),
                            "Associated": np.nan})

    for i, address in df["IP_Address"].iteritems():
        if address != address:
            continue 
        net_list = []
        for j, network in df["Network"].iteritems():
            if network.supernet_of(ipaddress.ip_network(f"{address}/{address.max_prefixlen}")):
                net_list.append(str(network))
                df.loc[i, "Associated"] = net_list
```

Example data:

```
Addresses = ['172.16.56.40','172.16.16.16']

Networks = ['172.16.56.0/24', '172.16.56.32/27']
```

Comment: Do you have example datasets that we could use to test? (of course no problem if it is smaller than the original set).

Comment: Can you add some statistics to the question here, how much time it takes for full execution ? time to run function is_subnet_of ?

Answer (score 3):

Bit operations will make it much faster, it also allows some expensive operations to be performed only once.

Consider the bellow function:

```py
def is_subnet_of(ip: str, network: str) -> bool:
    def bin_ip(ip: str) -> int:
        return int("".join(map(lambda n: bin(int(n)).replace("0b", "").zfill(8), ip.split("."))), 2)

    net, mask_len = network.split("/")
    mask_len = int(mask_len)

    # Convert ip and net to binary-format
    ip_bin = bin_ip(ip)
    net_bin = bin_ip(net)

    # Build mask
    mask = int(mask_len * '1' + (32 - mask_len) * '0', 2)

    # check (Bit operations are faster)
    return net_bin ^ (mask & ip_bin) == 0

# `is_subnet_of("172.16.56.40", "172.16.56.0/24")` will return True.
```

It takes 3 steps to decided whether the given `ip` is in the `network`:

1. Convert ip and net to binary-format(We need another function`bin_ip`to do this job)
2. Build the net mask
3. Do the check：`(net ^ (mask & ip))`

Even better, step1 and step2 only have to be performed once, which will save us most of the time:

```py
from typing import Tuple


def check_subnet(ip, network_list):
    def bin_ip(ip: str) -> int:
        return int(
            "".join(map(lambda n: bin(int(n)).replace("0b", "").zfill(8), ip.split("."))), 2
        )

    def bin_net(net: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        net_ip, mask_len = net.split("/")
        mask_len = int(mask_len)

        net_bin = bin_ip(net_ip)
        mask = int(mask_len * "1" + (32 - mask_len) * "0", 2)

        return net_bin, mask

    def is_subnet_of(ip: int, network: Tuple[int, int]) -> bool:
        return network[0] ^ (network[1] & ip) == 0

    ip = bin_ip(ip)
    networks = tuple(map(bin_net, network_list))

    return tuple(is_subnet_of(ip, network) for network in networks)


# Below are the test section
address_and_networks = {"172.16.56.40": ["172.16.56.0/24", "172.16.56.32/27"]}

result = tuple(check_subnet(ip, network_list) for ip, network_list in address_and_networks.items())

print(result)
```

---

If you insist using pandas vectorization operations, then I suggest:

1. Use the `bin_ip` function I mentioned above to construct matrixs of ip, network, and mask (this step will be O(n) complexity)
2. Use numpy matrix operations (as we all know, pandas actually uses numpy to complete numerical calculations) to calculate the result:`result = ((ip & mask) == net.T)`

In this way, we will do the O(n) complexity ourselves and leave the O(n^2) part to pandas/numpy vectorization operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was more directed towards the pandas dataframe part of my method, and not so much the calculating of IPs in Networks. This is where the bottleneck currently exists, because at present I'm having to loop through the dataframe line by line, which is not good.

Comment: Under the given requirements, O(n^2) iteration seems inevitable. Even if pandas built-in functions (such as apply) are used, it will be called to run the iterations. Therefore, I think no matter which IP-check method is used, the key is to extract the calculation steps as far as possible from the O(n^2) iteration (such as I mentioned in the answer),  then leave the rest part to pandas/numpy vectorization operations, which will exponentially reduce the running time.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into O(n^2) complexity.

As you mentioned, len(IP_addresses_list) = 31995 and len(Network_list) = 54099. Currently you are looping all 31995 * 54099 iterations and so causing the slowness.

Just for rough idea the same length loop doing nothing(just a pass statement) took almost 4 mins on online python compiler website. It still took a little over 1 min on my machine.

You need to reduce the iterations happening inside `is_subnet_of` function.

1. One approach here is break from the loop whenever possible. Do you see any conditions when your result is complete or you no longer need to continue the loop on Network_list (inside is_subnet_of function)?
2. Another approach is reduce your search list (Network_list). Convert it into dictionary with key as first 3 parts of IP address. And in `is_subnet_of` loop only the shorter list matching first 3 parts of IP address.

For example:

```
Addresses = ['172.16.56.40','172.16.16.16']
Networks = ['172.16.56.0/24', '172.16.56.32/27']
```

Convert your Network lists to dictionary for Networks

```
Networks = ['172.16.56.0/24', '172.16.56.32/27']
network_dict = {}
for n in Networks:
    network_dict.setdefault(n[:n.rfind(".")], []).append(n)
print(network_dict)
```

```
Output:
{'172.16.56': ['172.16.56.0/24', '172.16.56.32/27']}
```

So your `is_subnet_of` function will loop through for `172.16.56.40` and no loop for `172.16.16.16`

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual data, it is a bit hard to understand what exactly is happening, but some general advise could be:

- [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how='inner'` allows you to relatively fast check which values appear in two separate lists. So if you have one column containing the first three parts of IP addresses and another column containing network IPs (again only XXX.XXX.XXX and not the last part), this could already do the job. You might need to do some checking afterwards, but the number of operations would be much less. merge is vectorized making it a suitable candidate.
- [dask.apply](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply) could be used on a Dask DataFrame. This could be combined with [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) similar to the above-mentioned idea.

Once you provide example data, the suggestions above could be refined.